# Nesting UIViewControllers in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

Consider a `UIViewController` whose view contains the view of another `UIViewController`.

Is it correct to say that the parent `UIViewController` is responsible to call the lifecycle methods of the child controller? Methods such as:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
```

For example:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_childViewController viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

If so, which methods must be called?

Is there a better way to do this? Clearly the above approach is not forward-compatible: if a new lifecycle method is added the parent class needs to be modified to propagate the call of the new method.

Or is nesting view controllers simply a bad idea and should be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to add the view controller as a child view controller. You need to maintain both a view hierarchy (adding the view as a subview) and a view *controller* hierarchy (adding the view controller as a child). All of the life cycle methods are then called for you.

The relevant methods are `addChildViewController:` and `didMoveToParentViewController:`.

There was a talk on view controller containment in WWDC 2011, I recommend watching the video.

Comment: Ah, I totally missed these methods! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a hierarchy which still supports iOS 4, you would indeed need to forward the messages detailed in the documentation of the addChildViewController: yourself.

If iOS 4 is not targeted and you only need to build for ios 5 and later, stick with the new API as jrturton said.